# Easiest way to get next monday from current day?

Tags: php

I am looking for easiest method to find next Monday or some other day for example in php using mktime() or DateTime()

### Sample Data -> Result

Today is 15th Feb 2016 - Monday -> 22nd Feb 2016 - Monday
Today is 16th Feb 2016 - Tuesday -> 22nd Feb 2016 - Monday
Today is 22nd Feb 2016 - Monday -> 29th Feb 2016 - Monday
Today is 24th Feb 2016 - Wednesday -> 29th Feb 2016 - Monday

Comment: Hint: _date('w', time())_ returns the day of the week index, where 0 = Sunday, 1 = Monday, etc.

Comment: `new DateTime('next monday')`?

Comment: Also, suggest you use time() instead of mktime(), I believe mktime() is deprecated now. In many cases, using it won't let the script run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

okay use this,

```
$nextMonday = strtotime('next monday');
```

Comment: You are welcome ! In addition,thanks for choosing best answer.

Comment: How to get next monday date after a particular date ?

Answer (score 3):

I have a preference to the `DateTime()` object personally because I find it a lot more flexible than `date()`. In the example below you have a stored `DateTime()` object that you can easily perform further modifications/formats on as you see fit rather than if you use `date()`.

Here's an example of its usage:

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->modify('next monday');

echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

You can find a list of supported DateTime formats [here](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php) which you can use, a few examples being: `next week`, `+2 day`, `-3 month`.

For outputting the date you can find a list of formats [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Any more information you want, you're welcome to ask away. ^^

Answer (score 1):

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('next monday'));
```

Refer http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php for getting the exact format of date. I have just used the basic Y-m-d format

Although I find date function very easy to use, but go for the other answer if you like a OO approach to your code.